# Collect HOA fees at closing

Tags: fees, hoa

If HOA fees are not yet due at closing are the fees the responsibility of the buyer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the contract of sale will direct how this is handled.

The most common solution is to pro-rate fees due but not paid at closing and to adjust the amount of funds that change hands at closing accordingly, and then to have the buyer pay them when they come due. Prepayment of the dues and pro-rating the amount in the other direction at closing is also possible.

Comment: There is nothing in the signed contract.   I am the seller.  What are my obligations? I do not want to cheat the buyer but they have pushed two other items not in the contract and I sold low telling them I am not coming off that price.